# emulator -avd does not launch the device

Tags: android, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

on Ubuntu 16.04 I have installed AndroidStudio and via its AVD manager GUI did create tow new devices. now on Terminal when I type `emulator -list-avds` it lists the devices correctly, but when run `emulator -avd <name>` I face errors:

```
[139684796983104]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib
Could not launch '/home/amir/../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory
```

How should I solve it?

Comment: same on Windows 10 after updating Android Studio and Android SDK to latest versions :(

Comment: @dean.huczok I figured it out, it might help you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both in Windows 10 and Ubuntu I was facing the same problem. the simple solution is that I had to go to the directory of `tools` then execute the command. for instance in windows.

```
$ cd C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
emulator -avd <deviceName>
```

also it is good to mention I wanted that for React-Native development, and [Expo XDE](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/installation.html) saved me

Comment: [Win10] I tried this, plus tried moving around my `%PATH%` entries so that `%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%/emulator` was before `/tools` and `/platform-tools`, only thing that worked was opening `cmd` prompt in Administrator mode. :P